# numeric date variable to actual date variable

Tags: r

I'm still kind of new to R programming and most of the difficulties I have had, have I found answers for but I can't seem to find an answer to this.
So, I have this dataset which includes a date variable. Unfortunately it is treated as a numeric variable becuase it is of the type "YYYYMMDD", that is for example "20120101". I would like to convert this into a regular date variable, for example of the type "YYYY-MM-DD", because I would like to calculate the length from one date to another, but I can't seem to figure out how. So how is the easiest/best way to convert a numerical variable into a specific date variable?

I'm looking forward to any of your answers.

Sincerely,
Emil Blicher

Comment: `?as.Date.Character` or use `lubridate`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is a base R option:

```
x <- 20180116
d <- as.Date(as.character(x), format="%Y%m%d")
d

[1] "2018-01-16"
```

By default, an R date will print in `YYYY-MM-DD` format, so you don't need to do any additional work after the call to `as.Date` with the appropriate format mask.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, I get the error "Origin needs to be given" (My Rstudio is in Danish, so I don't know the exact phrase in English).

Comment: Try my updated answer.  You need to convert your integer dates to character strings first.